# I have problem when I repair the pub package, this Problem found

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have problem when I repair the pub package, this Problem found.
This code of cmd when I run:

```
C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad>flutter pub cache repair
Downloading shrine_images 1.1.2...
Downloading flutter_staggered_grid_view 0.3.2...
Downloading flutter_localized_locales 1.1.2...
Downloading devtools 0.8.0+3...
Downloading video_player 0.10.6...
Downloading win32 1.7.3...
Downloading image 2.1.18...
Downloading flutter_gallery_assets 0.2.6...
Downloading google_fonts 1.1.0...
Downloading googleapis 0.55.0...
Downloading connectivity_for_web 0.3.1+2...
Downloading connectivity 0.4.9+3...
Downloading cupertino_icons 1.0.0...
Downloading dds 1.4.0...
Downloading crypto 2.1.5...
Downloading connectivity_macos 0.1.0+5...
Downloading convert 2.1.1...
Downloading coverage 0.14.1...
Downloading completion 0.2.2...
Downloading code_builder 3.4.1...
Downloading clock 1.1.0-nullsafety.1...
Downloading collection 1.15.0-nullsafety.3...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair connectivity_for_web 0.3.1+2. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_a41aaa41\archive.tar"
Downloading checked_yaml 1.0.2...
Downloading charcode 1.2.0-nullsafety.1...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair connectivity 0.4.9+3. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_4554ef\archive.tar"
Downloading cli_util 0.2.0...
Downloading characters 1.1.0-nullsafety.3...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair convert 2.1.1. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_4e245747\archive.tar"
Downloading camera 0.5.8+7...
Downloading built_value 7.1.0...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair completion 0.2.2. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_59ec833a\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair connectivity_macos 0.1.0+5. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_a1b08c29\archive.tar"
Downloading built_collection 4.3.2...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair dds 1.4.0. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_b7c8770a\archive.tar"
Downloading build_web_compilers 2.11.0...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair clock 1.1.0-nullsafety.1. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_ac1322f4\archive.tar"
Downloading build_test 1.2.2...
Downloading build_runner_core 5.2.0...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair collection 1.15.0-nullsafety.3. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_c0f5b40b\archive.tar"
Downloading build_runner 1.10.2...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair checked_yaml 1.0.2. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_5d1b62c9\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair charcode 1.2.0-nullsafety.1. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_29ed76c6\archive.tar"
Downloading build_resolvers 1.3.11...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair code_builder 3.4.1. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_cede9818\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair cli_util 0.2.0. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_f2bb0d32\archive.tar"
Downloading build_modules 2.11.3...
Downloading build_daemon 2.1.4...
Downloading build_config 0.4.2...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair crypto 2.1.5. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_6c21aa64\archive.tar"
Downloading build 1.3.0...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair characters 1.1.0-nullsafety.3. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_6fa2476b\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair camera 0.5.8+7. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_5180b540\archive.tar"
Downloading browser_launcher 0.1.7...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair built_collection 4.3.2. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_1c2ef47f\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair built_value 7.1.0. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_107ebc20\archive.tar"
Downloading boolean_selector 2.1.0-nullsafety.1...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair build_web_compilers 2.11.0. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_6e68aa9e\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair coverage 0.14.1. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_eb60446a\archive.tar"
Downloading bazel_worker 0.1.25...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair build_test 1.2.2. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_a1fb3805\archive.tar"
Downloading battery 1.0.6...
Downloading async 2.5.0-nullsafety.1...
Downloading battery_platform_interface 1.0.0...
Downloading args 1.6.0...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair build_runner_core 5.2.0. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_560d2e9\archive.tar"
Downloading archive 2.0.13...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair build_config 0.4.2. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_fe3ee9fc\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair build_modules 2.11.3. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_80f32cf8\archive.tar"
Downloading animations 1.1.2...
Downloading analyzer 0.39.17...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair build_runner 1.10.2. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_b0c0c15d\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair build_resolvers 1.3.11. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_9f954a71\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair build 1.3.0. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_8d7dda81\archive.tar"
Downloading _fe_analyzer_shared 7.0.0...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair build_daemon 2.1.4. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_a9ddbfaf\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair browser_launcher 0.1.7. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_7e49f92f\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair boolean_selector 2.1.0-nullsafety.1. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_5cc93cb4\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair bazel_worker 0.1.25. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_3a286fda\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair battery_platform_interface 1.0.0. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_a52e0f32\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair args 1.6.0. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_ede148c3\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair async 2.5.0-nullsafety.1. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_700b6e5d\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair battery 1.0.6. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_54e46113\archive.tar"
Downloading _discoveryapis_commons 0.2.0...
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair _discoveryapis_commons 0.2.0. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_b9bac9cc\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair _fe_analyzer_shared 7.0.0. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_99b28a7f\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair google_fonts 1.1.0. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_6f1930c4\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair flutter_localized_locales 1.1.2. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_b8e826d6\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair archive 2.0.13. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_ab64270a\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair analyzer 0.39.17. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_3bf46c67\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair win32 1.7.3. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_26f97af4\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair googleapis 0.55.0. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_40d0694\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair shrine_images 1.1.2. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_c71b884\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392

Failed to repair devtools 0.8.0+3. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_9d360e8f\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair video_player 0.10.6. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_2c0576e1\archive.tar"
CreateProcessW failed 1392
Failed to repair image 2.1.18. Error:
ProcessException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_75faea68\archive.tar"
```

I download the 7-zip program but in cmd. The problem file is corrupted and unreadabl.
I add 7z to variable environment.
flutter doctor no issuses.
I want to add flutter package `carousel_pro: ^1.0.0` but I have problem to command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib_internal\pub\asset\7zip\7za.exe x "C:\Users\Hamzah Al-haddad\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_75faea68\archive.tar"

Comment: Try to run `flutter clean` and check again

Comment: @Ashok the same problem